# Unity Google VR - getting the rotation, yaw, and pitch values from android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on converting a simple project of mine into a VR game. Currently, it's just a motorcycle that will zoom forward, and the player can use A or D (or left and right) to steer the cycle.

Here's my code so far:

```
void Start () {
    cycleSphere = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update () {
    inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (currentSpeed < maxSpeed)
        currentSpeed += acceleration;

    if (currentSpeed > 0)
        cycleSphere.transform.Rotate (0, inputX, 0);

    cycleSphere.velocity += transform.forward * currentSpeed;
}
```

I've imported GoogleVR SDK v1.70.0 and added the prefab, which allows me to view the game on my phone in VR and even look around without touching the code.

I want to make it so that if the player tilts his head left or right, the cycle will turn in the respective direction. How do I do that? Do I use `Input.Gyro`?

Comment: Without GoogleVR or any plugin: `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp( transform.localRotation, InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(VRNode.CenterEye), Time.deltaTime);` Don't forget to import `UnityEngine.VR`. Although I suggest using GoogleVR or other plugins since built-in VR API in Unity currently small/minimalist and is missing a-lot.

Comment: @Programmer, well, I am using GoogleVR. But I'm not sure where or how to use phone rotation values. The documentation is kinda sparse.

Comment: I forgot to mention I don't use GoogleVR and don't even do VR to begin with. You may want to check on Youtube or example scenes that comes with the GoogleVR SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this before, I made Pacman in Virtual Reality where tilting your head would steer the player (As in, tilting your head to the left so that your ear touches your shoulder, would steer the player, and vice versa).

I did it using `Input.acceleration`

For example, you can do something as simple as this:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0f, Input.acceleration.x * acceleratorSensitivity, 0f);
}
```

Basically, you take the X rotation of your device (which would be your head tilting), apply your sensitivity (higher sensitivity means faster turning), and rotate your transform accordingly! :-)

I also think this approach is better than using the gyroscope as not all devices contain a gyroscope, but the majority of devices contain accelerometers (which at its basic level, rotates the screen).

Comment: Well, I am making a VR game, which would require a gyro anyway. But this works, thanks!

Comment: Glad it works! Just a note - if you are going to publish this I would recommend a gyro check in your game that informs the user if their device has gyroscope. At first, I didn't have this check, and my game received a lot of negative of reviews as they thought the game was broken - when in fact their device didn't have gyro. If you're making something simple like this, using gyro and accelerometer is fine, but when you want full 360 degrees head tilt, I would suggest implementing a gyro check! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the main camera's `transform.eulerAngles` like so:

```
private float angle;

Update() {
    angle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
}
```

This gives you the number of degrees of tilt, where a low value means tilting to the left, and a high (~360) value means tilting to the right.

In my testing just now it seems to give values of up to +-10 depending on where you look, even without any rotation.